# Get a duplicated UIViewController instance after called performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, segue

********************** Updated: The problem has been solved!!
don't reply. thanks! :)

---

I am trying to implement multiple orientation for a UIViewController named RootViewController. It's the root view controller in the app.

I follow the instructions in the Apple's tutorial (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html) and implement the following code in the RootViewController class:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    ...
    // detect orientation changed
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];

    ....
}

- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    log(@"self: %@, orientation: %d", self, (int)orientation);

    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && !isShowingLandscapeView) {
        log(@"show landscape view");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"go_landscape" sender:self];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    } else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) && isShowingLandscapeView) {
        log(@"show portrait view");
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}
```

When I try to rotate the simulator to landscape mode, the orientationChanged method is called. But when I rotate it back, I see a very strange condition: The RootViewController get a duplicated instance(the original instance id = 0x7fc4eb813a00, and the duplicate one is 0x7fc4eb081800 in the following log).

```
-[RootViewController orientationChanged:] [Line 796] self: <RootViewController:
0x7fc4eb813a00>, orientation: 1
-[RootViewController orientationChanged:] [Line 796] self: <RootViewController:   
0x7fc4eb813a00>, orientation: 3
-[RootViewController orientationChanged:] [Line 800] show landscape view
-[RootViewController orientationChanged:] [Line 796] self: <RootViewController: 
0x7fc4eb813a00>, orientation: 1
-[RootViewController orientationChanged:] [Line 804] show portrait view
-[RootViewController orientationChanged:] [Line 796] self: <RootViewController: 
0x7fc4eb081800>, orientation: 1
```

If I rotate it to landscape mode again, the app will crash as the following log. (The duplicated one doesn't have the segue.)

```
-[RootViewController orientationChanged:] [Line 796] self: <RootViewController: 
0x7fc4eb081800>, orientation: 3
-[RootViewController orientationChanged:] [Line 800] show landscape view
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Receiver (<RootViewController: 0x7fc4eb081800>) has no segue with 
identifier 'go_landscape''
*** First throw call stack:
```

The storyboard:

[image]

The segue setting:

[image]

I really don't know why this happened. I create a new project to test orientation changed implementation, the strange condition won't happen. Any direction to investigate?

Comment: Haven't gone through the Apple's tutorial, but your exception is pretty straight-forward. In your story-board you don't have any segue with the identifier of `go_landscape`, therefore when you are trying to perform that segue, your app crashes.

Comment: no, the storyboard did have a segue named "go_landscape". the original instance did perform it successfully(notice the the second line of log). so the log shows "show landscape view" and no crash happened. I won't make a stupid mistake like this. lol

Comment: Can you show your orientation change implementation of the second view controller? Since it happens on the rotation back, I don't think the code above is the cause of the crash.

Comment: It's the same view controller - RootViewController. If I mark the code in the orientationChanged method. Then app won't crash any more, and no duplicated RootViewController instance is created.

Comment: It's probably the same **class** of view controller, but not the same **instance**, since you are 'segueing' into it.

Comment: so you mean the performSegueWithIdentifier method will produce another instance even it's the same class?

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted is DESIGNED to create a new view controller when you switch to landscape orientation. The `performSegue` method creates a new view controller. That's how it works.

I always try to avoid creating a new view controller just to support a different orientation. Instead I set up code to adjust to the geometry change. I'm better at using old style resizing masks than I am at AutoLayout, but I've used both approaches.

Answer (score 0):

oh my... the performSegueWithIdentifier method did create another instance, even it's the same class. I have found the root cause why app will crash.

In my new project, when orientation changed, the log display like the following. The new created instance will be dealloc when call dismissViewControllerAnimated method to dismiss self.

```
self: <RootViewController: 0x7f99d1518890>, orientation: 3, isShowingLandscapeView: 0
show lanscape view
self: <RootViewController: 0x7f99d1518890>, orientation: 1, isShowingLandscapeView: 1
show portrait view
self: <RootViewController: 0x7f99d1727500>, orientation: 1, isShowingLandscapeView: 0
[RootViewController dealloc] [Line 35] !!!!!! dealloc instance: <RootViewController: 0x7f99d1727500>
```

But, the log in my original project doesn't display like the above... the new created instance doesn't be dealloc! so it will crash because the second instance is created based on second story UIViewController layout, and it doesn't contain the segue "go_landscape".

```
self: <RootViewController: 0x7fc142818400>, orientation: 3, isShowingLandscapeView: 0
show landscape view
self: <RootViewController: 0x7fc142818400>, orientation: 1, isShowingLandscapeView: 1
show portrait view, self: <RootViewController: 0x7fc142818400>
self: <RootViewController: 0x7fc142200600>, orientation: 1, isShowingLandscapeView: 0
self: <RootViewController: 0x7fc142818400>, orientation: 3, isShowingLandscapeView: 0
show landscape view
self: <RootViewController: 0x7fc142200600>, orientation: 3, isShowingLandscapeView: 0
show landscape view
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<RootViewController: 0x7fc142200600>) has no segue with identifier 'go_landscape''
```

But why!??? Both of these two projects use ARC mechanism and process the same code. Why the new instance in the new project will be dealloc normally, but the new instance in the original project won't be dealloc!???????

Must fix this problem, or it will cause memory leak when orientation changed because it always creates a new garbage instance.

Answer (score 0):

oh my god............ I know why the new instance in the original project won't be dealloc. Because it will create a NSTimer object and keep running. So the instance never be dealloc. Alright, it's my fault. ~"~

```
- (void) startTimer {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(tick)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}
```